# Apple Watch string is getting truncated

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

In my app there is a big string of about 40 lines and I'm trying to put it on the Apple Watch. When I open it only 10 lines are being displayed and rest of the sting is getting truncated with dots. How can I show the entire string on the Apple Watch so that users can keep scrolling down.

Comment: Are you using a WKInterfaceLabel? If so, that is not going to scroll. Create a WKInterfaceTable with only a label per row group. You can substring your master string into individual rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a `WKInterfaceLabel` that shows *multiline* text in my Watch app with no problem.

There is something you miss

Set number of Lines to `0`.   *(I 'm sure you set this already)*

Set the height of label to  `Size To Fit Content` (I guess you set it fixed may be mistakenly)

Check if your `Label` is in some `WKInterfaceGroup`. if so then you might have set fixed height for Group. change it to `Size To Fit Content` too.